# WPF- Hyperlink to another view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, hyperlink

I am working with MVVM and WPF.

I want to make a textblock with Hyperlink that when I click it, it change View in WPF application.

I tried writing NavigateUri="Folder/View.xaml" but it but not served.

In the NavigateUri How to would write the direction to my other View?

Comment: Great, what have you tried so far? What's the problem?

Comment: Better? The problem is that, when I write the direction the link does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
<TextBlock Margin="3" TextWrapping="Wrap">
      This is a simple page.
      Click <Hyperlink NavigateUri="/Namespace;component/TargetPage.xaml">Click here</Hyperlink>.
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I tried writing NavigateUri="Folder/View.xaml" but it but not served. Is neccessary write NameSpace?